# Google Chrome Inconsistent Group Policy Settings

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10-preview

Here's a fun one for ya's.

[image]

When my computer was running Windows 7, I mucked around with some registry stuff for Google Chrome. I've forgotten exactly what. It may have been so it let me run Chrome Canary independently or something in that vein.

I've since patched my system to Windows Technical Preview.

Occasionally I find Chrome displaying a little notification in the top-right of the browser window saying that it can not update and that it needs to reinstall. Not only does clicking on the link to reinstall take me to the page about their space project, but trying to re-use a chrome installer I have on my system produces the linked message.

I feel I am doomed to not be able to update Chrome ever again. Not that there's anything wrong with the current build, it's just that since getting an Android phone I can sign in to Chrome on it but cannot sync bookmarks and whatnot due to an inconsistent passphrase. Not that I recall ever setting a passphrase, but it could only be so many things, and none of them work, so I'm guessing that also circles back to this issue.

Ps. I have since uninstalled Chrome Canary / don't consider it in this issue.

To be clear:

My problem is not being able to update Chrome due to inconsistent group policy settings, apparently.

My question is: What can I do about it?

Comment: Unless you explain what you did exactly we can't help.  There are far to many grammatical and formatting problems in this question, honestly, the question is barely understandable for that reason.  I cannot inline your screenshot for you if you use the .png extension on the image.

Comment: I am obviously unable to provide any info on what exactly I changed, else I would have.

I'm looking for a possible answer from someone who possibly knows how to reset the Group Policy settings to default, remove them completely and have them rebuilt by chrome, something of that sort.

Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: Simplest solution would be delete them, since they are not part of the default set of group policy templates, then install them again.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that even if you've messed around a little with the registry editor, you can download a group policy template from Google, which can be found [here](http://dl.google.com/update2/enterprise/GoogleUpdate.adm). Once you do this, just follow [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/186330/how-to-fix-and-adjust-automatic-updating-in-google-chrome/) and you should have no trouble getting it to all work nicely again. (i.e. updating, syncing, as per normal)

Thanks to @Ramhound for the suggestions.